# Why had code inside if (false) statement been read?

Tags: javascript

What I want to achieve: if something went wrong (`if (false)`), re-define object `A`. Then, create new variable `a` to assign to `A`.

```js
class A {

}
class B {
  
}
class C {
  constructor() {
    if (false) {
      console.log('hit'); // never hit to
      var A = B
    }
    var a = A; 
    console.log(a) // undefined
  }
}
var c = new C();
```

I'm not sure the line `var A = B` was executed, but if I remove the `if` statement, `console.log(a)` would print:

```
class A {

}
```

My question: Why am I getting `undefined` in the line `console.log(a)`?

Comment: vars are hoisted at parsing, not at execution

Comment: As soon as you're using ES2015 - switch to `let`/`const`, there is no really reason to use `var` anymore.

Comment: Can you explain why you expected a different result?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit obviously because variable hoisting is not an intuitively clear concept.

Comment: @zerkms: No but specifically what the OP expected and why would save us from having to guess which misunderstanding to correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `var` statements in a function, regardless of where they appear, are treated as if they appeared at the top of the function. Thus, your function is interpreted exactly as if it were written:

```
class C {
  constructor() {
    var a, A;
    if (false) {
      console.log('hit'); // never hit to
      A = B
    }
    a = A; 
    console.log(a) // undefined
  }
}
```

Thus because the variables `a` and `A` appear *somewhere* in the constructor function in `var` declarations, they're declared throughout the entire function. The *initializations* of the declared variables are evaluated where the `var` declarations actually appear.

Comment: Might want to include in your answer that this is known as "hoisting"

Comment: @Cyoce yes, it's a form of "hoisting" and the way `var` works is generally referred to by that term.